# Setting a default image

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set a default image for my image upload form. In the database I have the column "deafult_image" and it will be set to 1 for default and set to 0 if the image is not default.

My problem right now is I can update a row to 1 to make an image the default but if another image exists and is default "1" then I will have 2 default images. How can i update my default image but also change the current default image to 0 at the same time to make it not default anymore.

The media_id column is unique.
link_id is not and could have multiple images for any given link_id.

Here is what I came up with for updating the row to make the image default.

```
$media = $_GET['media_id'];
$media_id = '1';
$sql = "select * FROM images where media_id = '$media'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
mysql_query("UPDATE images SET default_image='$media_id' where media_id = '$media'") ;
}
```

What should I do to find if another image with the same link_id exists and change it from 1 to 0 if it is default. There is always a default image for every link_id so I need to update to the current default image.

Also I know I need to validate, this is just for testing.

Comment: use REPLACE instead of UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will reset every image to 0

```
$sql = "UPDATE images SET default_image='0'";
```

This will set your relevant image as the default

```
$sql = "UPDATE images SET default_image='1' where media_id = '$media'";
```

Comment: Thanks, works good. I was making it more complicated then it needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly. so you just need to find the current default, set it to 0, and set the new default to 1. 
and if you are afraid that some exception would happen and you can't set a new default image, you can save the current default image in a variable, set the new default image and then find the previous default image by it's id (saved in the variable) and set it to 0.

Comment: Yes that is exactly right. I will see what I can come up with.